# Text not wrapping, instead opts to go under

Tags: html, css

**My Problem**
So I am trying to create a news section for my website. Each section contains a title, an image, and the article itself. The problem is that the article text will refuse to go beside the image unless I use `<br>` to break it up myself.

**Description**
All the elements of each section is listed under a single div element. The section includes the title, image, and article. After that, the picture has its own class and the article also to CSS after.

1. The Title is a block element
2. The Picture is an inline-block element
3. The Article is an inline-block element

**HTML CODE (STARTING FROM NEWS BOX NOT INCLUDING NAV BAR AND ABOVE)**

```
<div id=newsboard>
    <div class=newsboard_topic>
        <h1>Website in Development!</h1>
        <img src="/image/newsboard/construction.gif" alt="Dev">
        <p class=newsboard_topic_article>
            Greetings!
            <br>The GeoVillage website is currently under construction, but feel free to register and login to check out the stuff we have so far!
            <br>- Geo Jones 
            <br>Owner and Developer
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class=newsboard_topic>
        <h1>kimmy and donald!</h1>
        <img class=newsboard_topic_picture src="/image/newsboard/kimdon.jpg" alt="kimmyanddonald">
        <p class=newsboard_topic_article>
            The fan fiction of Donald Trump and Kim Jong Un! Yes, they photoshopepd it. This is a test by the way to test the standing of articles.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE FOR SECTION OF HTML**

```csss
#newsboard {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border-color: #0099FF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}

.newsboard_topic {
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
}

.newsboard_topic_article {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.newsboard_topic_picture {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE**
is currently up at geo-village.com

Answer (score 0):

Make the picture a floating element inside the text container, then the text will float next to it (and below it, if it's longer)

Comment: Added float:left; to .newsboard_topic_picture. not working.

Comment: Did you put it INTO the `.newsboard_topic_article` `<p>` tag, as I wrote?

Comment: Yep. Tried putting float:right; into .newsboard_topic_article, made it worse.

Comment: No, no float on the `p`tag - the `<img>` tag (with `float: left`) has to be INSIDE the `<p>`tag (no float, but `display: block`!)

Comment: Alright. NEW HTML CODE: #newsboard {
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-right: 100px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 border-color: #0099FF;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
}

.newsboard_topic {
 padding: 20px;
 display: block;
}

.newsboard_topic_article {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
}

.newsboard_topic_picture {
 display:block;
 float: left;
}

Comment: that was css. I cannot edit posts for some reason. Here is my HTML.    <div class=newsboard_topic>
    <h1>kimmy and donald!</h1>
    <p class=newsboard_topic_article>
     <img class=newsboard_topic_picture src="/image/newsboard/kimdon.jpg" alt="kimmyanddonald">
     The fan fiction of Donald Trump and Kim Jong Un! Yes, they photoshopped it. This is a test by the way to test the standing of articles.
    </p>
    </div>
   </div> How can i make it so i can add padding to the paragraph it self? sorry for the formatting. i dont know how to use this comment thing yet,

Comment: add `margin-right: 10px` (or whatever px) to `.newsboard_topic_picture`, and maybe also `margin-bottom` (try which values fit best)

Comment: alright working ;) look at the live example though. the first article is actually formatted so some have break lines, but one long string isnt. Right now the long string is cut up. Check the html in my original post, it is changed but the text contents inside the <p> isnt. Some have <br> some dont

Comment: well, just reduce the width of the container (p)

Comment: No, I mean that right now the parts i didnt put <br> on is automatically shrinking and warping. It is suppose to go the full length of the container - the padding.

Comment: Like for example, the donald trump post is expanding, but tthe under co one isnt, even though one of the liens are line with <br>

Answer (score 0):

Separate your `newsboard_topic` class.

```
    <div class=newsboard_topic>
        <img src="/image/newsboard/construction.gif" alt="Dev">
        <h1>Website in Development!</h1>

    </div>

 <p class=newsboard_topic_article>
            Greetings!
            <br>The GeoVillage website is currently under construction, but feel free to register and login to check out the stuff we have so far!
            <br>- Geo Jones 
            <br>Owner and Developer
        </p>
```

Then give your `newsboard_topic` class a `display:flex;`.

```
.newsboard_topic {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the obvious answer no one wanted to give, which would make a lot of your coding more smooth is... Bootstraps. If you are learning to code, I highly recommend learning from some of the great opensource solutions available.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h1>Website in Development!</h1>
        <img src="/image/newsboard/construction.gif" alt="Dev">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p class=newsboard_topic_article>
        Greetings!
        <br>The GeoVillage website is currently under construction, but feel free to register and login to check out the stuff we have so far!
        <br>- Geo Jones 
        <br>Owner and Developer
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```